# Magento collection issues, methods not working filters not applied etc

Tags: collection, filter

Trying to create a couple of quick extensions, one to display a list of best sellers and one to display a list of items on promotion.  I want both of these modules to filter by a given cateogry id if one is supplied.  So I found out that magento has a built in module that isn't used in the default theme namely the `catalog/product_list_promotion` rather than create something from scratch I thought I would try to modify this module and also use it as a base for the best seller module.  So I found some examples of a best seller module and used the code to create best seller module, both the promotion module and the best seller module are working and displaying products.  The problem is I can't apply category filters and I can't limit the number of results, I've tried every combination of adding the filters/limits/page sizes etc and either i get no errors but the original unchanged output or a fatal error to an undefined method.  I have searched for hours for a solution and found some similar questions on SO and other forums, all suggest what I have already tried which hasn't worked, maybe someone can help?

So in `Mage/Catalog/Product/Block/List/promotion.php` I have:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Promotion extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
            Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            // your custom filter
        $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('promotion', 1)->addStoreFilter();
            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding `$c...->setLimit(X)`, `$c...->limit(X)` `$c...->getSelect()->limit(X)`, `$c...->page(1, X)`, `$c...->setPageSize(X)` both before and after prepareCollection...  In most cases I get no errors but no limit is applied.  the best sellers module is essentially the same so  wont post the code as I assume the issue with this will be the same for the best sellers module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Tried adding `$collection->load()` and this seems to fix the problem, I assume my filters etc were being overridden in another class somewhere when the $collection is loaded.  I didn't do this initially I was under the impression Magento didn't load the collection until it was needed allowing you to modify it at any point until it is loaded, I wanted to keep that functionality...

Comment: For any future visitors - if you call `$collection->load` explicitly you're effectively defeating lazy loading.